# java string.matches requires matches of too much of the string

Tags: java, regex, string

The following code:

```
String s = "casdfsad";
System.out.println(s.matches("[a-z]"));
System.out.println(s.matches("^[a-z]"));
System.out.println(s.matches("^[a-z].*"));
```

outputs

```
false
false
true
```

But why is that? I did not specify any `$` at the end of any of the patterns.
Does `String.matches` add `^` and `$` implicitly to force a full string match?
Why? And can I disable full string matching, perhaps by using another method?

Edit:

If String.matches implicitly adds `^` and `$`, why don't `String.replaceAll` or `String.replaceFirst` also do this? Isn't this inconsistent?

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistent? `matches` doesn't check if regex can be found in some part of the string, but if string **matches** regex entirely. To check if regex can be found in string you can use `find()` method from `Matcher` class. `replaceAll` works as other `relace` methods, but uses regex as argument to let replace substrings that matches regex be replaced with something else. `replaceFirst` works similar but will stop after first replacement. These all methods make sense and are very intuitive (at least for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no `find` method in `String` you must use `Matcher.find()`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("casdfsad");
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

will output

```
true
```

**EDIT**: If you want to find full strings and you don't need regular expressions you can use `String.indexOf()`, e.g.

```
String someString = "Hello World";
boolean isHelloContained = someString.indexOf("Hello") > -1;
System.out.println(isHelloContained);

someString = "Some other string";
isHelloContained = someString.indexOf("Hello") > -1;
System.out.println(isHelloContained);
```

will output

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try, by putting `+` of greedy quantifier you can match whole `String`. Because, `s` has more than one character. So,to match you should choose a quantifier which will match, more than one `a-z` range character.  For `String.matches`, you don't need boundary character `^` and `$`.

```
String s = "casdfsad";
System.out.println(s.matches("[a-z]+"));// It will be true
```

Comment: Yes, but my question is why I have to match the entire string instead of just a substring.

Comment: Because, s has more than one character. So,to match you should choose a quantifier which will match, more than one a-z range character.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a single character regex for a Sring?

You could try :

```
String s = "casdfsad";
System.out.println(s.matches("[a-z]+"));
System.out.println(s.matches("^[a-z]+"));
System.out.println(s.matches("^[a-z].*"));
```

The third one matches because of the *. String.matches is not adding any  ^ and $ implicitly to force a full string match.